# Ideal way to finding errors in Exim's log file

Tags: linux, exim

I have a HUGE massive Exim mail log. What is going to be a good way to go through this email log and pull out all the common and other error types so I can go in and look them up and see which ones need to be fixed?

Would using grep to find error types work then extract them?
Is there a script or tool that already does this?

For example I have an error like

```
R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-45): SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM
```

and

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: host mx-apac.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net [106.10.166.52]: 451 Message temporarily deferred - [160]
```

**To summarize, I need to find errors in the error log without going through line by line so I can see if there is anything serious.**

Answer (score 1):

The `eximstats` program's report will include errors in its output.  You may want to run it against the rotated logs when they are rotated.  It gives a good overview of how your mail is being handled.  Looking at its code, it appears you mat be able to find errors by grepping for `**`.

The `paniclog` includes the most significant errors.

The `rejectlog` may be easier to scan as it includes only messages which were rejected.